# How to delete the file that is created in the Document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

I created a database file using the following code

```
// Get the documents directory
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = dirPaths[0];

// Build the path to the database file


databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDB.db"]];
```

How can I remove the file "MyDB.db" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do a little searching before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a file with the following

```
NSError *error;
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:databasePath error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error while removing file: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```